# How to get hyperlink value in c# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

hello i am using below dropdown menu so user can filter by certain value the problem is how can i get the selected value from this dropdown- menu

```
  protected void btnsearch1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
           grid.DataSource = U.Search(//Selected Value, txtsearch.Text);
            grid.DataBind();
            grid.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }
```

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li><a href="#contains">Contains</a></li>
<li><a href="#its_equal">It's equal</a></li>
<li><a href="#greather_than">Greather than ></a></li>
<li><a href="#less_than">Less than < </a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a href="#all">Anything</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try here http://code.runnable.com/UjB_wxmQpvw8AAAw/asp-net-how-to-use-dropdownlist

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything in your code to send it to the server.

In your javascript, you'd want to add:

```
        var param = $(this).attr("href").replace("#","");
        var concept = $(this).text();
        var options = [param, concept];

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {userOptions:options},
            url: '/Home/Index',
            dataType: 'json'
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            // handle response
        })
        .error(function (req, status, error) {
            $('#result').html('Error: ' + error);
        });
```

Then on your sever you could receive the data with:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Destinations(IEnumerable<string> userOptions)
    {
        // do something with userOptions...
        JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
        result.Data = someData;
        return (result);
    }
```